# How to call the function for date and display in the slot with next 6days

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this [DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/preetisingh/qg4qwwat/)
I want to display the date slot with current date and next 6 days. I have this HTML CODE:

```
<div class="date_slide">
     <div id="date-slider" class="dragdealer">
         <ul class="list_date">
            <li id="date1">
                 SAT<br>2</br>APR
            </li>
            <li id="date2">
                SUN<br>3</br>APR
            </li>
            <li id="date3">
                MON<br>4</br>APR
            </li>
            <li id="date4">
               TUS<br>5</br>APR
            </li>
            <li id="date5">
                 WED<br>6</br>APR
            </li>
            <li id="date6">
                THU<br>7</br>APR
             </li>
             <li id="date7">
                 FRI<br>8</br>APR
             </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="handle red-bar">
             <span class="value"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var current_date = new Date();
var next_date = new Date();
var i,j;

var date = current_date.getDate();

var tot_days = new Array(7);
var dd, mm;
for(j=0; j<7; j++){
dd = next_date.getDay();

mm = next_date.getMonth();
if(mm==0){
mm="JAN";
}else if(mm==1){
mm="FEB";
}else if(mm==2){
mm="MAR";
} else if(mm==3){
mm="APR";
 } else if(mm==4){
mm="MAY";
} else if(mm==5){
mm="JUN";
} else if(mm==6){
mm="JUL";
} else if(mm==7){
mm="AUG";
} else if(mm==8){
mm="SEP";
} else if(mm==9){
mm="OCT";
} else if(mm==10){
mm="NOV";
} else if(mm==11){
mm="DEC";
}  

if(dd==0){
dd="SUN";
}else if(dd==1){
dd="MON";
}else if(dd==2){
dd="TUE";
}else if(dd==3){
dd="WED";
}else if(dd==4){
dd="THU";
}else if(dd==5){
dd="FRI";
}else if(dd==6){
dd="SAT";
}

tot_days[j] = next_date.getDate() + "<br>" + dd + "<br>" + mm;
next_date.setDate(next_date.getDate() + 1);
document.write(tot_days[j]);
```

This JS show the day, date and month fine as I wanted. But I am confused how shall I apply this JS in the code so that the dates which are hard coded now shows the correct dates following with next 6 days. Any suggestions please. Its not necessary that it should be javascript, jquery will also work for me. I just need this thing to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `document.write(tot_days[j])`:

```
document.getElementById("date" + (j + 1)).innerHTML = tot_days[j];
```

Comment: Your's is coming perfect dont know what wrong with the code let me check again

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end

Comment: It worked Thank you so much. I have one more query I am using this in the Dragdealer JS which is the slider and on thumb I want to display the similar value like this https://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/ they have done it for the numbers I want to do the same thing for date also; The current Jas is:

$(function() {    
  new Dragdealer('date-slider', {
    speed: 1,
    loose: true,
    steps: 7,
    animationCallback: function(x, y) {
      $('#date-slider .value').text('SAT\n2\nAPR');
    }
  });
 })  
 I have hardcoded that can you help me implement this as well

Comment: I have never used dragdealer but try `tot_days[x]` instead of `'SAT\n2\nAPR'`

Comment: it showing the current date only in the text() function any idea if I move the slide should increment the date